# What throws DOMErrors

Tags: javascript, dom4

### Introduction

[DOMError](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#domerror) is an interface defined by the DOM.

I would like to check whether a browser supports it. A naive check is

`window.DOMError !== undefined`

A better check would be to use an action that throws a DOMError and check that

`err instanceof DOMError === true`

### Question

What actions throw DOMErrors?

Comment: Why is the second method better? I typically use the first method for support checks.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff because checking `window.foo` checks it exists. Checking `thing works as expected` checks it actually works as expected. For example event if `window.Event` exists you don't know whether `new Event("click");` will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `DOMError` is a non-exception-based error condition. It will never be thrown, except in as much as an object that implements both `DOMError` and `DOMException` might be thrown as a `DOMException`.

It is expected that the concrete class implementing `DOMError` and `DOMException` may be the same in many DOM implementations, but they are separated in the spec for the benefit of languages with bindings to `DOMException` that would make it hard to re-use the existing implementation. For example languages without native exceptions may have an out-of-band error-signalling channel that can't really be dumped as an object onto a property like a `DOMError` can.

DOMError as drafted in DOM4 is a trivial placeholder, holding only a name string. It is expected that any specs that build on it will add some properties to encapsulate more useful information.

Currently it is used by the W3 [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) for errors in `FileReader`, which, being an asynchronous interface, doesn't have anywhere useful to throw exceptions. The File API doesn't add any extra properties to `DOMError` or a subinterface as yet, but both it and the DOM4 spec are likely to undergo changes before they get near Recommendation status.

DOMError as originally introduced in DOM Level 3 Core provided an extended error interface with more in-depth information on where in the document the error occurred. It was intended for the serialiser and parser processes in DOM Level 3 LS, but is included in Core for the use of the `document.normalizeDocument` method, which also simulates a serialise/parse cycle.

Today's browsers don't have a DOMError because they don't support any of DOM 4, DOM Level 3 LS , or `normalizeDocument`. But other non-browser DOM implementations may; [pxdom](http://www.doxdesk.com/software/py/pxdom.html) for one has the DOM 3 interfaces.

Comment: many modern browsers support most of dom4 (try `new Event("click")`)

Comment: That only works in the very latest WebKit and Opera (indeed it only appeared in the spec back in September). The other significant new feature would be the DOM manipulation methods (`replace()` et al) which only turned up in the new January draft and nothing supports them yet. It's way too early even to know for sure what ‘supporting DOM4’ will mean!

Comment: my opinion is that dom4 is the living dom spec just like what html is a living spec. so one can never support dom4

Answer (score 1):

It's not implemented in Firefox ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOMError)), Chrome 17 has it neither.

The w3 documentation on this is really vague. See this statement:

*This interface is intended for other specifications that want to introduce error handling through other means than exceptions. It is expected that the exception types are reused.*

As far as I can see, methods throw [DOMException](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-17189187). Since this is labled *interface* (instead of *exception*), I assume it should be implemented and not used.

This existed in [DOM Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ERROR-Interfaces-DOMError) too, by the way.

**Edit:** After reading ThinkingStiff's comment, I am pretty sure it should not be thrown ever. You can not even throw it yourself (Opera 11.52):

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'DOMError' is not a constructor  
Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'DOMError' is not a function
```

It's also an interface in Java's DOM implementation: [DOMError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/DOMError.html).

Comment: The object exists in Opera. Still trying to get it to throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

DOMErrors are caused when trying to create an invalid DOM element, or passing a non-existent node as an argument to node manipulation methods. In other words, an exception is raised when an operation is impossible to perform.

Example:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div:foo");
```

This causes a DOMError when div:foo doesn't exist.

Comment: Opera is the only browser I can find that supports it and it's throwing a `DOMException` for this, not a `DOMError`.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("div:foo")` throws a `DOMException`, not a `DOMError`